# Math.sqrt showing error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, math.sqrt

This is the code for a calculator app for Android I'm making:

```
package com.example.calculator;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.lang.Math;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class main extends Activity {
    GridView mKeypadGrid;
    TextView userInputText;
    TextView memoryStatText;

    Stack<String> mInputStack;
    Stack<String> mOperationStack;

    KeypadAdapter mKeypadAdapter;
    TextView mStackText;
    boolean resetInput = false;
    boolean hasFinalResult = false;

    String mDecimalSeperator;
    double memoryValue = Double.NaN;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat
                .getInstance();
        char decimalSeperator = currencyFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols()
                .getDecimalSeparator();
        mDecimalSeperator = Character.toString(decimalSeperator);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the stack
        mInputStack = new Stack<String>();
        mOperationStack = new Stack<String>();

        // Get reference to the keypad button GridView
        mKeypadGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdButtons);

        // Get reference to the user input TextView
        userInputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
        userInputText.setText("0");

        memoryStatText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMemory);
        memoryStatText.setText("");

        mStackText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStack);

        // Create Keypad Adapter
        mKeypadAdapter = new KeypadAdapter(this);

        // Set adapter of the keypad grid
        mKeypadGrid.setAdapter(mKeypadAdapter);

        // Set button click listener of the keypad adapter
        mKeypadAdapter.setOnButtonClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button btn = (Button) v;
                // Get the KeypadButton value which is used to identify the
                // keypad button from the Button's tag
                KeypadButton keypadButton = (KeypadButton) btn.getTag();

                // Process keypad button
                ProcessKeypadInput(keypadButton);
            }
        });

        mKeypadGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void ProcessKeypadInput(KeypadButton keypadButton) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, keypadButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String text = keypadButton.getText().toString();
        String currentInput = userInputText.getText().toString();

        int currentInputLen = currentInput.length();
        String evalResult = null;
        double userInputValue = Double.NaN;

        switch (keypadButton) {
        case BACKSPACE: // Handle backspace
            // If has operand skip backspace
            if (resetInput)
                return;

            int endIndex = currentInputLen - 1;

            // There is one character at input so reset input to 0
            if (endIndex < 1) {
                userInputText.setText("0");
            }
            // Trim last character of the input text
            else {
                userInputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(0, endIndex));
            }
            break;
        case SIGN: // Handle -/+ sign
            // input has text and is different than initial value 0
            if (currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput != "0") {
                // Already has (-) sign. Remove that sign
                if (currentInput.charAt(0) == '-') {
                    userInputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(1,
                            currentInputLen));
                }
                // Prepend (-) sign
                else {
                    userInputText.setText("-" + currentInput.toString());
                }
            }
            break;
        case CE: // Handle clear input
            userInputText.setText("0");
            break;
        case SQRT:
            userInputText.setText(Math.sqrt(currentInput));
            break;
        case C: // Handle clear input and stack
            userInputText.setText("0");
            clearStacks();
            break;
        case DECIMAL_SEP: // Handle decimal separator
            if (hasFinalResult || resetInput) {
                userInputText.setText("0" + mDecimalSeperator);
                hasFinalResult = false;
                resetInput = false;
            } else if (currentInput.contains("."))
                return;
            else
                userInputText.append(mDecimalSeperator);
            break;
        case DIV:
        case PLUS:
        case MINUS:
        case MULTIPLY:
            if (resetInput) {
                mInputStack.pop();
                mOperationStack.pop();
            } else {
                if (currentInput.charAt(0) == '-') {
                    mInputStack.add("(" + currentInput + ")");
                } else {
                    mInputStack.add(currentInput);
                }
                mOperationStack.add(currentInput);
            }

            mInputStack.add(text);
            mOperationStack.add(text);

            dumpInputStack();
            evalResult = evaluateResult(false);
            if (evalResult != null)
                userInputText.setText(evalResult);

            resetInput = true;
            break;
        case CALCULATE:
            if (mOperationStack.size() == 0)
                break;

            mOperationStack.add(currentInput);
            evalResult = evaluateResult(true);
            if (evalResult != null) {
                clearStacks();
                userInputText.setText(evalResult);
                resetInput = false;
                hasFinalResult = true;
            }
            break;
        case M_ADD: // Add user input value to memory buffer
            userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
            if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                return;
            if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                memoryValue = 0;
            memoryValue += userInputValue;
            displayMemoryStat();

            hasFinalResult = true;

            break;
        case M_REMOVE: // Subtract user input value to memory buffer
            userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
            if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                return;
            if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                memoryValue = 0;
            memoryValue -= userInputValue;
            displayMemoryStat();
            hasFinalResult = true;
            break;
        case MC: // Reset memory buffer to 0
            memoryValue = Double.NaN;
            displayMemoryStat();
            break;
        case MR: // Read memoryBuffer value
            if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue))
                return;
            userInputText.setText(doubleToString(memoryValue));
            displayMemoryStat();
            break;
        case MS: // Set memoryBuffer value to user input
            userInputValue = tryParseUserInput();
            if (Double.isNaN(userInputValue))
                return;
            memoryValue = userInputValue;
            displayMemoryStat();
            hasFinalResult = true;
            break;
        default:
            if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0))) {
                if (currentInput.equals("0") || resetInput || hasFinalResult) {
                    userInputText.setText(text);
                    resetInput = false;
                    hasFinalResult = false;
                } else {
                    userInputText.append(text);
                    resetInput = false;
                }

            }
            break;

        }

    }

    private void clearStacks() {
        mInputStack.clear();
        mOperationStack.clear();
        mStackText.setText("");
    }

    private void dumpInputStack() {
        Iterator<String> it = mInputStack.iterator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            CharSequence iValue = it.next();
            sb.append(iValue);

        }

        mStackText.setText(sb.toString());
    }

    private String evaluateResult(boolean requestedByUser) {
        if ((!requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 4)
                || (requestedByUser && mOperationStack.size() != 3))
            return null;

        String left = mOperationStack.get(0);
        String operator = mOperationStack.get(1);
        String right = mOperationStack.get(2);
        String tmp = null;
        if (!requestedByUser)
            tmp = mOperationStack.get(3);

        double leftVal = Double.parseDouble(left.toString());
        double rightVal = Double.parseDouble(right.toString());
        double result = Double.NaN;

        if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.DIV.getText())) {
            result = leftVal / rightVal;
        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MULTIPLY.getText())) {
            result = leftVal * rightVal;

        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.PLUS.getText())) {
            result = leftVal + rightVal;
        } else if (operator.equals(KeypadButton.MINUS.getText())) {
            result = leftVal - rightVal;

        }

        String resultStr = doubleToString(result);
        if (resultStr == null)
            return null;

        mOperationStack.clear();
        if (!requestedByUser) {
            mOperationStack.add(resultStr);
            mOperationStack.add(tmp);
        }

        return resultStr;
    }

    private String doubleToString(double value) {
        if (Double.isNaN(value))
            return null;

        long longVal = (long) value;
        if (longVal == value)
            return Long.toString(longVal);
        else
            return Double.toString(value);

    }

    private double tryParseUserInput() {
        String inputStr = userInputText.getText().toString();
        double result = Double.NaN;
        try {
            result = Double.parseDouble(inputStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }

        return result;

    }

    private void displayMemoryStat() {
        if (Double.isNaN(memoryValue)) {
            memoryStatText.setText("");
        } else {
            memoryStatText.setText("M = " + doubleToString(memoryValue));
        }
    }

}
```

To find the Square root of an inputted number, I use the following code:

```
   import java.lang.Math;
    case SQRT:
        userInputText.setText(Math.sqrt(currentInput));
        break;
```

But its showing error in this line:

```
userInputText.setText(Math.sqrt(currentInput));
```

Error: The method sqrt(double) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Why is this, and can someone help me fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Read* the error message:

> `userInputText.setText(Math.sqrt(currentInput));`
>   Error: The method sqrt(**double**) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (**String**)

It's telling you that you're calling `Math.sqrt` with a `String` argument where it expects a `double` (a floating point numeric value). And, indeeed, that *is* the case:

```
String currentInput = userInputText.getText().toString();
```

If you have a string and you want to turn that into a double, you should be looking at something like `Double.parseDouble()`:

```
double dInput;
try {
    dInput = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    doSomethingIntelligent();
}
// Now have dInput which can be passed to `sqrt()`.
```

Keep in mind that, once you *have* the square root as a double, you can't just blindly pass that to `setText()`, you'll need to turn it back into a string first.

Provided you're certain the initial string will be a valid double, you can replace your problematic line:

```
userInputText.setText(Math.sqrt(currentInput));
```

with something like:

```
double dVal = 0;
try {
    dVal = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
dVal = Math.sqrt(dVal);
userInputText.setText(String.valueOf(dVal));
```

Comment: double dInput;
try {
    dInput = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        userInputText.setText(Math.sqrt(currentInput));
    }
}

Comment: @user2201935, I made it a bit more explicit down the bottom - replace your problematic line with the segment I provided. You can't do a `setText(double)` because that function needs a `CharSequence` like a string. You also appear from your comment, to be setting the text field only if an exception occurs. Suggest you re-examine the final code section of mine, it's intent is to _ignore_ the exception.

Comment: Sorry, I am still struggling. Actually I am using case statement. But your code is breaking my case statement.

Comment: @user2201935: no probs, I think it was a missing brace from my `try/catch` which I fixed up recently.

Answer (score 0):

Because Math.sqrt method takes double argument. Parse your string to double.

```
userInputText.setText(String.valueof(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(currentInput))));
```

Comment: What does `sqrt` return? And what does `setText` take as a parameter?

Comment: I get this error now in the same line - The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (double) if I use the code which you gave.